# LLVM ERROR: Broken function found, compilation aborted

Tags: ios, swift, abaddressbook, xcode6

Here are couple of simple lines in swift:

```
let umAB: Unmanaged<ABAddressBookRef> = ABAddressBookCreate()
let ab: ABAddressBookRef = umAB.takeRetainedValue()
```

The second line breaks code compilation, here's the error that I get:

```
Bitcast requires both operands to be pointer or neither
%27 = bitcast %objc_object* %26 to %PSs9AnyObject_, !dbg !170
LLVM ERROR: Broken function found, compilation aborted!
Command /Applications/Xcode6-Beta2.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift failed with exit code 1
```

Any ideas what's wrong with the second line?

Comment: first use createwithoptions method. AddressBookCreate is deprecated

Answer (score 1):

This is late, but the answer is simple: **This is a bug in the compiler.**  `LLVM ERROR` implies that bad LLVM IR has been generated, and that is a bug in the calling program.

Comment: That is way too general an answer, "a bug in the calling program".  You can say that about every question on here.

Comment: A compiler still should not crash, though.  That said, this question will not be helpful to readers nowadays,